# Beginner JS calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am new into the world of JS, and I'm trying to build a basic calculator.
Everything work fine so long but I have problem displaying different elements on the result screen of the calculator.

When I click 1 then 2, 1 will disappear but I want it to stay for my calculation.

Please help!!

```js
var displayText = document.getElementById('displayText');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
function add(){
  var two, plus, result;
  result = displayText.value;
  output.innerHTML = result;
}
function addOne() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one').value = 1;
      displayText.value = one;
}
function addTwo() {
  var two = document.getElementById('two').value = 2;
      displayText.value = two;
}
function addPlus() {
  var plus = document.getElementById('plus').value = "+";
      displayText.value = plus;
}
```

```html
 <div>
  <div class="display">
    <input type="text" id="displayText" name="" value="">
    <p>The result of your calculation is: <span id="output"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_wrap">
    <button id="one" onclick="addOne()">1</button>
    <button id="two" onclick="addTwo()">2</button>
    <button id="plus" onclick="addPlus()">+</button>
    <button id="" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `+=` to concatenate the value string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `=`, you just need to use `+=`. `=` will reset the value whereas `+=` will append/concatenate the values. And you can use `eval()` to get the sum (in this case) of entered expression.

Below is the updated snippet for you:

```js
var displayText = document.getElementById('displayText');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function add() {
  var two, plus, result;
  result = displayText.value;
  output.innerHTML = eval(result);
}

function addOne() {
  var one = document.getElementById('one').innerText;
  displayText.value += one;
}

function addTwo() {
  var two = document.getElementById('two').innerText ;
  displayText.value += two;
}

function addPlus() {
  var plus = document.getElementById('plus').innerText ;
  displayText.value += plus;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="display">
    <input type="text" id="displayText" name="" value="">
    <p>The result of your calculation is: <span id="output"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_wrap">
    <button id="one" onclick="addOne()">1</button>
    <button id="two" onclick="addTwo()">2</button>
    <button id="plus" onclick="addPlus()">+</button>
    <button id="" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The result is a string of the calculation, not the actual result. Is this expected?

Comment: Well, I thought of that, as OP is learning JS. But I have updated my answer with `eval()` now.

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the value of the text field everytime you call one of your functions. You don't want to set a new text each time, you want to append the new text to the old text. So replace

```
displayText.value = one;
```

with:

```
displayText.value += one;
```

for each time you want to append text.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/urfvrtej/) is a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you are replacing existing value in textbox so, it will disappear
replace the addOne() and addTwo() functions with below code

```
function addOne() {
                var one = document.getElementById('one').value = 1;
                        displayText.value = displayText.value + one;
            }
            function addTwo() {
                var two = document.getElementById('two').value = 2;
                        displayText.value =displayText.value + two;
            }
```